# How to make Debian 10 boot faster

Tags: debian, boot, logs

I have following configuration installed on my system,

```
mercurial@providence:~$ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          mercurial@providence 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       -------------------- 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: XPS L501X A08 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 4.19.0-6-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 7 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 2883 (dpkg) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.0.3 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1366x768 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: MATE 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: Metacity (Marco) 
  `Y$$                        WM Theme: TraditionalOk 
   `Y$$.                      Theme: Clearlooks [GTK2/3] 
     `$$b.                    Icons: gnome [GTK2/3] 
       `Y$$b.                 Terminal: mate-terminal 
          `"Y$b._             Terminal Font: Monospace 10 
              `"""            CPU: Intel i5 M 460 (4) @ 2.534GHz 
                              GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 420M 
                              GPU: Intel Core Processor 
                              Memory: 1062MiB / 3683MiB 




mercurial@providence:~$ uname -a
Linux providence 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now the problem is system is taking way too long to boot, following is the startup plot.

```
mercurial@providence:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 38.520s (kernel) + 26.496s (userspace) = 1min 5.017s 
graphical.target reached after 26.478s in userspace
```

https://svgshare.com/i/FNK.svg

I tried to fix some of the stuff but couldn't get to the depth of it.

My boot log is as follows,

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
Debian: clean, 934549/7528448 files, 9966424/30091008 blocks
[  OK  ] Started Set console font and keymap.
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
         Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
[  OK  ] Started Load AppArmor profiles.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.
[  OK  ] Started Raise network interfaces.
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:dell::kbd_backlight...
[  OK  ] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:dell::kbd_backlight.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
         Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Found device ST9500420AS 7.
         Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896...
[  OK  ] Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started Trigger anacron every hour.
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt download activities.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Started Daily rotation of log files.
[  OK  ] Started Daily man-db regeneration.
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Manage Sound Card State (restore and store).
         Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
         Starting System Logging Service...
[  OK  ] Started Run anacron jobs.
         Starting Bluetooth service...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting Modem Manager...
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
         Starting Deferred execution scheduler...
         Starting Disk Manager...
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting WPA supplicant...
         Starting Login Service...
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
[  OK  ] Started Deferred execution scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.
[  OK  ] Started WPA supplicant.
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Started Bluetooth service.
[  OK  ] Reached target Bluetooth.
[  OK  ] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
         Starting Authorization Manager...
         Starting Hostname Service...
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager.
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
         Starting Light Display Manager...
[  OK  ] Started Hostname Service.
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[  OK  ] Started Authorization Manager.
[  OK  ] Started Accounts Service.
```

Note that i searched something for that `GAVE UP WAITING FOR...` and someone directed towards this,

```
mercurial@providence:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    UUID=fee92c6d-7b60-4014-a66b-c48cd9094162
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries 
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the 
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs 
    integration and avoid this warning.
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda7
I: (UUID=c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-5-amd64
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    UUID=fee92c6d-7b60-4014-a66b-c48cd9094162
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries 
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the 
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs 
    integration and avoid this warning.
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda7
I: (UUID=c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

That `/dev/sda7` is my swap file.

```
mercurial@providence:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST9500420AS     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc8000000

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 170128349 169921502    81G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       170144408 337927335 167782928    80G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       337930238 976769023 638838786 304.6G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       337930240 727652351 389722112 185.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       727654400 968382463 240728064 114.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       968384512 976769023   8384512     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


mercurial@providence:~$ ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Oct  7 23:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Oct  7 23:45 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct  7 23:46 129C98019C97DE13 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct  7 23:46 3D9D2B1C080C3A89 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct  7 23:46 480488312682F440 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct  7 23:46 aec68856-488a-4c50-aa05-01af59b3ae0b -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct  7 23:46 c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct  7 23:46 d96d4546-92a2-49bf-b9d0-c00348d42395 -> ../../sda5
```

How can i boot faster, maybe in less than 10 seconds perharps?

Comment: Check `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: It may have some delay but if its not an SSD 1 minute doesnt seem terribly slow.

Comment: I have attached whole plot [here](https://svgshare.com/i/FNK.svg) also in the question, In userspace network manager and swap takes some time, but even my kernel is loading in 38 seconds.  `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` displays some error about missing UUID, which was previously UUID of my swap, which got changed when i installed another OS.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, basically UUID's got mixed up after disabling and deleting my swap inside a virtualbox. This caused timeout issues and dependency failures, and it forced a file system check on each boot. I had to update my UUIDs accordingly.

If a swap partition is deleted (e.g. on purpose when migrating from HD to SSD), the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` should be either completely empty or read `RESUME=`. Delete any UUID number. `RESUME=NONE` is not valid. Whether or not you are using a swap the fix is in see below:

For troubleshooting (optional):

```
sudo cat /var/log/boot.log
```

List correct partition UUIDS:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
```

Make sure the following three files have the correct UUID set as listed by blkid, overwrite them with the correct UUID:

```
/etc/fstab                                      [for me swap was incorrect]
/etc/default/grub                               [for me RESUME=UUID was incorrect]
/boot/grub/grub.cfg                             [for me RESUME=UUID was incorrect]
```

Then update Initial Ram File-System:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Editing the three files above also permanently solved my `cryptsetup: error: couldn't resolve device` errors when running update-initramfs

This should prevent the need of adding the UUID to `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, however, in the case that you still have an issue consider adding a UUID for example: `RESUME=UUID=c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896`, or set `RESUME=` if you are using no swap file.

Then run:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Also make sure `/etc/default/grub` has set to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`, to speed up boot process. After everything I describe here, it performed one final filesystem check on boot but but after that it booted in 10 seconds instead of 1 minute and 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
mercurial@providence:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.913s (kernel) + 20.621s (userspace) = 28.534s 
graphical.target reached after 20.605s in userspace
```

[image]

This is what i have achieved after rectifying some of the problems. As you can see the startup time gradually decreases from 1 min 5 sec to 28 secs.

**1. sudo update-initramfs -u -k all : Kernel Time**

This was screaming at top of its lungs that i was trying to resume from a device which was not to be found, i.e. i had a resume block in my `grub.cfg`

```
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    UUID=fee92c6d-7b60-4014-a66b-c48cd9094162
```

This is just a bug,

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries 
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the 
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs 
    integration and avoid this warning.
```

And this nice line of code was asking me to declare the new swap partition so my system can resume from it,

```
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda7
I: (UUID=c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

And so i did,

```
mercurial@providence:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=UUID=c0198c37-f28b-41f5-bb0f-37d575e86896
```

**2. systemd-analyze blame : Userspace Time**

My network manager was taking some time to come online, so all i had to do is mask it.

```
sudo systemctl mask NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

## RESULTS

Now i am down to 28 seconds boot time and following are my blame and critical chain,

```
mercurial@providence:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @20.605s
└─udisks2.service @9.969s +10.636s
  └─basic.target @9.515s
    └─sockets.target @9.515s
      └─dbus.socket @9.515s
        └─sysinit.target @9.333s
          └─swap.target @9.333s
            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c0198c37\x2df28b\x2d41f5\x2dbb0f\x2d37d575e86896.swap @8.843s +490ms
              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c0198c37\x2df28b\x2d41f5\x2dbb0f\x2d37d575e86896.device @8.841s
mercurial@providence:~$ systemd-analyze blame
         10.636s udisks2.service
          6.628s dev-sda6.device
          5.486s ModemManager.service
          4.935s accounts-daemon.service
          4.346s exim4.service
          4.156s NetworkManager.service
          3.211s bluetooth.service
          3.203s atd.service
          3.174s apt-daily.service
          3.132s pppd-dns.service
          3.128s alsa-restore.service
          2.765s systemd-logind.service
          2.762s avahi-daemon.service
          2.751s rsyslog.service
          2.750s wpa_supplicant.service
          2.594s networking.service
          2.168s lightdm.service
          2.148s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          2.024s upower.service
          1.975s systemd-udevd.service
          1.955s apparmor.service
          1.718s polkit.service
          1.412s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.161s colord.service
          1.000s systemd-rfkill.service
```

I believe there is alot of room for improvement, so i'll just wait for some hardcore system administrators to shed some light. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/default/grub put profile in place of quit and splash
Sudo update-grub
Edit /etc/fstab chance 1 OR 2 in 0
Mask network manager wait online
Mask Plymouth wait online
Reboot